# How to use Zombie while debugging iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, nszombie

How to use Zombie while debugging iPhone application?

Comment: http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about setting up an environment variable. See the following article for details
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Take good care of not letting this in place because **no memory will ever be free**.

Answer (score 0):

You can open up Instruments and choose the Zombie instrument and next your app target from the 'Choose Target' drop down menu. And use your app till it crashes this will lead you to the Zombie object that causes it to crash.
Remind not to use the Leak instrument with the Zombie one since it will show many leaks (the objects not deallocated kept in memory to test if they can be zombies in the futures) and remember it will use lots of memory so you'd better you the simulator for this task.